# Get desktop folder path by username

Tags: windows, path, lua, directory, desktop

I'm working with moonscript and looking for a solution that will help to get desktop folder path using account user name which is registered in the system (not current user). What if user changes desktop location. Admin's priviledge is applied. Did somebody face this? Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to enumerate where the user profile is located at all. The path to a profile can be found in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-xxx:ProfileImagePath. S-1-5-21-xxx represents the SID of the user in question.

Then you need to load ntuser.dat from that profile path to finally grab the User Shell Folder registry value for the desktop folder.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm...
Have You tried `os.getenv("CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY")`?
It should work according technet@microsoft[1]

Way more dirtier way would be trying to read windows registry (HKCU > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Explorer > User Shell Folders > Desktop) with some kind of Lua Windows Registry API [2].

[1] http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749104(v=ws.10).aspx

[2] http://lua-users.org/wiki/WindowsRegistry

Comment: Thank you. These work only for the current user. I tried cmd "runas" command to relaunch appl but it always wants password of the target user even if application works under admin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, think I found solution.

1. Get user SID
2. Get user profile path from
  *"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\{User SID}\"->"ProfileImagePath"*
3. Get user folders from:
   *"HKEY_USERS\{User SID}\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"*, replace %userprofile% with path from prev point
   It has desktop folder path.

PS: This doesn't work for built-in accounts.

Comment: Please remember that HKU\(SID) is only valid as long as the user in question is logged on...